# nifi:jolt: tranformation needed for different names with array formation of each name

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Here is my input and based one filenamepath we will be grouping and add those recpective files into single array for each group.

```json
[
  {
    "filename": "FF/raw/first/raw_A/filenameA_20240212002113.DAT"
  },
  {
    "filename": "FF/raw/first/raw_A/filenameA__20240205150101.DAT"
  },
  {
    "filename": "FF/raw/first/raw_B/filenameB_20240212002113.DAT"
  },
  {
    "filename": "FF/raw/first/raw_B/filenameB_20240205150101.DAT"
  }
]
```

and output is required in below format:

```json
[
  {
    "raw_A": [
      "filenameA_20240212002113.DAT",
      "filenameA_20240205150101.DAT"
    ]
  },
  {
    "raw_B": [
      "filenameB_20240212002113.DAT",
      "filenameB_20240205150101.DAT"
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following **shift** transformation specs :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*/*/*/*/*": "&(0,4).&(0,5)"// extract the leaf node by using 5th asterisk, eg. use &(0,5)
                                      // and penultimate one by &(0,4)
                                      // after splitting the whole path by slashes
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // convert objects into independent arrays
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$": "&2.[#2]"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // rearrange the JSON as desired
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[#2].&1"
      }
    }
  }
]
```